# How can I convert an Option<&str> to BSON?

Tags: rust

Here is my Rust program:

```
#[macro_use(bson, doc)]
extern crate bson;
extern crate mongodb;

extern crate hyper;
extern crate regex;

use std::io::Read;

// Hyper
use hyper::Client;
use hyper::header::Connection;

// Regex
use regex::Regex;

// MongoDB
use mongodb::{Client as MongoClient, ThreadedClient};
use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;
use mongodb::error::Result as MongoResult;

// bson
use bson::{Bson, Document};
use bson::oid::ObjectId;

fn main() {
    // Create a client.
    let client = Client::new();

    // Creating an outgoing request.
    let mut res = client.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films:_J%E2%80%93K")
        // set a header
        .header(Connection::close())
        // let 'er go!
        .send().unwrap();

    // Read the Response.
    let mut body = String::new();
    res.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();

    // Regex out the li tags with movies names
    let re = Regex::new("<li><i><a href=\"[^\"]+\" title=\"[^\"]+\">(?P<title>[^<]+)").unwrap();
    for caps in re.captures_iter(&body) {
        // Connect to database
        let mclient = MongoClient::connect("localhost", 27017)
                          .ok()
                          .expect("Error establishing connection.");

        // The titles collection
        let coll = mclient.db("rust-test-titles").collection("titles");

        let title = caps.name("title");

        let doc = doc!{"value" => title};

        // Insert our title
        coll.insert_one(doc.clone(), None)
            .ok()
            .expect("Failed to insert document.");
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this I get the error:

```
error: the trait `core::convert::From<core::option::Option<&str>>` is not implemented for the type `bson::bson::Bson` [E0277]
<bson macros>:10 $ val : expr ) => { { :: std:: convert:: From:: from ( $ val ) } } ;
```

How can I convert `title` so `bson` won't throw an error?

Comment: If the problem is with the `doc!` macro of the bson crate, and potentially its interaction with the `regex` crate, then there is nothing specific to MongoDB here. Please produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), where minimal means removing all the extra fluff (MongoDB, connecting to other servers, ...) and complete means adding back the imports that you use so we do not have to guess which crate you depend on.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I can make it work if I don't try to add the regex result. I've added the crates I'm using

Comment: @user3666882 Listen to what MattheiuM. is saying. There's no reason to be including HTTP fetches or `let coll = ...` or any of that if the error is with `doc!`.

Comment: Does `fn main() { doc! { "value" => Some("foo") }; }` replicate the error?